# How to get elements which contains "NN-NN" N - number

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Example xml:

```
<Documents>
<Product>
<Name>ŁYŻWOROLKI PB X-ONE 34-37 PINK</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>ŁYŻWOROLKI PB X-ONE 37-40 PINK</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>ROLKI VIVA INLINE SPEED 2000 R.42 RED ABEC-3</Name>
</Product>
</Documents>
```

Hello, i need to copy elements which contains (NN-NN) in name like "34-37" or "37-40", is it possible in xslt?

output:

```
<Documents>
<Product>
<Name>ŁYŻWOROLKI PB X-ONE 34-37 PINK</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>ŁYŻWOROLKI PB X-ONE 37-40 PINK</Name>
</Product>
</Documents>
```

Comment: what expected output

Comment: Could you have NNN-NN in your text? If so, would you want this to be matched too, or just NN-NN? Thanks.

Comment: only NN-NN is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it along the way of :

```
<xsl:template match="/Documents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Product[contains(translate(Name, '0123456789#', '##########@'), '##-##')]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Use with care because you might get false positives if the mark (`#`) is present between the digits. I would not strip the mark but translate it to some char different from those in the "mask". Example: `contains(translate(Name, '0123456789#', '##########&'), '##-##')`